# How to add newly created Stored Procedure to the application using code first in C# MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, code-first

I have already generated code first from database in my application. Now I have a new stored procedure created in my database. How can I update the model with the new SP in my application.

Is there any option, like UPDATE MODEL FROM DATABASE like in context file in EF for CodeFirst too.
I have to use CodeFirst only, no other option.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffold an empty change by executing the following in the Package Manager Console:

```
add-migration AddStoredProcedure
```

Then, you'll get a migration with an empty Up() and Down() method.  You then create some code to execute the CREATE PROCEDURE SQL you want to add in the Up() method, and add code to the Down() method which executes "DROP PROCEDURE".  (There's a Sql() method in the DbMigration base class, so you can use that.).

Then it's a case of letting the migration do its work, or triggering it by calling:

```
update-database
```

For future updates to the procedure, the Up() SQL needs to be "ALTER PROCEDURE" instead of "CREATE PROCEDURE" and the Down() method needs to put back the previous version of the procedure.

To make it easier to read than concatenating SQL together as strings, I normally add the stored procedures as .sql files to the EF DLL (as embedded resources).

Comment: Bear in mind that since you already added the stored procedure(s) to your database manually, you should drop them first, or the Up() method will fail to create the procedure (because the procedure will already exist).